# Oracle APEX i.war file referencing file share broken image

Tags: weblogic, oracle-apex, oracle-apps

I have a strange problem with oracle apex when updating images or css.

The setup is APEX 4.2.6 in web logic.

The i.war file has been created so it references a shared folder that developers can upload and change.

The change enabled the designers to reference images as normal in CSS due to substitution variables not allowed in external files.

I can then reference an image with say the following path ;

/i/mycompany/images/logo.png

This works great, then I change the logo and overwrite file.... Apex now returns a broken image ( but the HTTP response code is still 200) - weird.

If I save the file as logo2.png and then reference all is fine.

It must be cache somewhere , the drastic measure is I'm going to see if bouncing web logic hosted i.war helps , but I this wouldn't be a great solution for each change :).

In the past with images hosted in the workspace I have purged the apex files tables, but like i say these files are outside on a file system.

Any Ideas thoughts out there from the APEX community.

Cheers